# Three inequalities of indices

Tags: combinatorics, inequality

Given are real numbers $(a_1)_{i=1}^n,(b_1)_{i=1}^n,(c_1)_{i=1}^n$ in $[0,1]$, and positive real numbers $A,B,C$. Can we always divide the set $I=\{1,\dots,n\}$ into three sets $I_a,I_b,I_c$ such that
$$\sum_{i\in I_a}a_i\geq A\cdot \max\left(\frac{\left(\sum_{i\in I_b}a_i\right)-1}{B}, \frac{\left(\sum_{i\in I_c}a_i\right)-1}{C}\right)$$
and two analogous inequalities hold for $b_i$ and $c_i$? One of these inequalities is:

$$\sum_{i\in I_b}b_i\geq B\cdot \max\left(\frac{\left(\sum_{i\in I_a}b_i\right)-1}{A}, \frac{\left(\sum_{i\in I_c}b_i\right)-1}{C}\right)$$

If $A=B=C$, this statement is true. We can simply choose the indices in a cyclic manner, with the highest $a_i$ going into $I_a$, the highest remaining $b_i$ going into $I_b$, the highest remaining $c_i$ going into $I_c$, and so on. But this doesn't seem to extend to unequal values of $A,B,C$.

Comment: are $-1$s outside the $\sum$?

Comment: With the symmetry broken after the edit, it is somewhat ambiguous what the "two analogous inequalities" are. Is one of them $$\sum_{i\in I_{\color{red}b}}b_i\geq {\color{red}B}\cdot \max\left(\frac{\left(\sum_{i\in I_{\color{red}a}}b_i\right)-1}{\color{red}A}, \frac{\left(\sum_{i\in I_c}b_i\right)-1}{C}\right)?$$

Comment: May I suggest that the comment of @HagenvonEitzen be edited into the problem statement?  I also found "two analogous inequalities" a little ambiguous at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Heuristic argument / too long for a comment**

I've been thinking about the following approach for a day or two, but I couldn't prove or disprove anything.  Maybe someone else can proceed further with it.  My key idea is to generalize the greedy approach in the OP.

The OP's greedy approach is strict round-robin.  This makes sense when $A=B=C$.  However, when $A,B,C$ are unequal, this reminds me of the difference between **(unweighted) fair queueing**, vs **weighted queueing** (in a server).  More precisely, I'm imagining assigning an $i$ to $I_a$ as equivalent to serving customer $a$.  So when $A=B=C$, the $3$ customers have equal priority and the round-robin method serves them equally (up to the $-1$ terms in the RHS of the inequalities).  But when $A,B,C$ are unequal this means each customer has a different intrinsic priority and their services must be equal (again, up to $-1$ terms) after rescaling by $\frac1A, \frac1B, \frac1C$.

One classic way to do weighted queueing is to keep track of "credits".  To be precise, everyone starts with zero credits $F_a = F_b= F_c = 0$.  Whenever customer $a$ is served, its credit increments $F_a := F_a + \frac1A$.  At every turn, serve the customer with the least credit i.e. $\arg \min(F_a, F_b, F_c)$.  I'm not sure how to break ties but as a concrete example we can break ties alphabetically, just like in the OP round-robin.  And to "serve" customer $a$ means to pick the largest remaining $a_i$ and assign that index $i$ to $I_a$.

In the original case of $A=B=C$, what I described above is identical to the OP's strict round-robin $abcabcabc$...

In the simplest unequal example, say $A=B=1$ and $C=2$, we end up serving the customers in the order $abccabccabcc$...  So customer $c$ gets served twice (two indices are added to $I_c$) for every time customer $a$ or $b$ gets served (for every index added to $I_a$ or $I_b$).  So set $I_c$ gets to be twice as big, but every summation involving $\sum_{i \in I_c}$ gets divided by $C=2$, so things even out.  In fact, in this simplest case, since the order of service is very regular, it is easy to prove that inequalities are respected.

However, when the values $\frac1A, \frac1B, \frac1C$ are less simple, I cannot find a proof.  I tried various invariants but nothing worked.  I also tried proving the very special case of $\forall i: a_i = b_i = c_i$ but that didn't work either.  (I had hoped that, after proving this very special case, I can further find an argument as to why all other cases are "easier" than this, by taking advantage of the fact that "serving" customer $a$ means picking the largest remaining $a_i$.)

Anyway, hopefully this is useful to somebody...

Answer (score 0):

I think greedy works.

Suppose we already partition $[n-1]$ into $I_a, I_b, I_c$ such that the inequalities hold. Now we want to put $n$ into $I_a, I_b$ or $I_c$ such that the inequalities still hold. For simplicity, let's denote $S_a = \sum_{i\in I_a}a_i$, and similar for $B, C$.
Suppose $\frac{S_a}{A}$ is minimum among $\{\frac{S_a}{A}, \frac{S_b}{B}, \frac{S_c}{C}\}$.
We claim that we may put $n$ into $I_a$ and do not violate anything. Otherwise, it could only violate
$$
\frac{\sum_{i\in I_b}b_i}{B} \ge \frac{(\sum_{i\in I_a}a_i) -1}{A}
$$
or
$$
\frac{\sum_{i\in I_c}c_i}{C} \ge \frac{(\sum_{i\in I_a}a_i) -1}{A}
$$
 So we have
$$
\frac{S_b}{B} < \frac{S_a + a_n -1}{A} \text{ or  }\frac{S_c}{C} < \frac{S_a + a_n -1}{A} 
$$
which implies 
$$
\frac{S_a}{A}-\frac{S_b}{B} > \frac{1-a_n}{A} > 0 \text{ or  }\frac{S_a}{A}-\frac{S_c}{C} > \frac{1-a_n}{A} > 0
$$
contradict to the minimality of $\frac{S_a}{A}$.